# Mockito defining 'when' invokes the answer

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I need to mock a JDBC update statement, and I want to make sure that the update string sent is the correct one. I have a MockConnectionManager that has the following method defined for defining the expected query strings:

```
public void setUpdateExpectedQuery(String ...expectedQueryStrings) throws SQLException {

    Statement mockStatement = mock(Statement.class);
    when(mockConnection.createStatement()).thenReturn(mockStatement);

    when(mockStatement.executeUpdate(anyString())).then(new Answer<String>() {

        @Override
        public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
            String str = Arrays.toString(invocationOnMock.getArguments());
            throw new RuntimeException("Update string is not as expected: " + str);
        }

    });

    for(String expected : expectedQueryStrings) {
        when(mockStatement.executeUpdate(expected)).then(new Answer<Void>() {

            @Override
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
                // Do something, just don't throw an exception here.
                return null;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

I want that if an unexpected query string was encountered an exception will be thrown. The query strings we expect are below as mentioned in the Mockito wiki (http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2).

For some reason, when executing the test and just calling the setUpdateExpectedQuery, an exception is thrown.

```
MockConnectionManager connectionManager = (MockConnectionManager) context.getBean("connectionManager");

connectionManager.setUpdateExpectedQuery("INSERT WHATEVER INTO WHENEVER");
```

The same exception as written in the first Answer: java.lang.RuntimeException: Update string is not as expected: [INSERT WHATEVER INTO WHENEVER]

How is this possible? is calling 'when' actually invokes the method? I never saw it happening in other cases...

Comment: *What* exception is thrown?

Comment: The one in the first Answer: java.lang.RuntimeException: Update string is not as expected: [INSERT WHATEVER INTO WHENEVER]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that your calls within the loop (when you call `mockStatement.executeUpdate(expected)`) match your earlier mock of `when(mockStatement.executeUpdate(anyString()))`.

Remember that the way the mock knows what you're calling within the `when` is *because you're calling it* - imagine translating `when(mockStatement.executeUpdate(anyString()))` into:

```
int result = mockStatement.executeUpdate(anyString());
OngoingStubbing<Integer> tmp = when(result);
tmp.then(...);
```

It may be that you just need to have a *single* `when(...)` call. So:

```
public void setUpdateExpectedQuery(String ...expectedQueryStrings)
    throws SQLException {
    final Set<String> capturedQueries = new HashSet<>
       (Arrays.asList(expectedQueryStrings);

    Statement mockStatement = mock(Statement.class);
    when(mockConnection.createStatement()).thenReturn(mockStatement);

    when(mockStatement.executeUpdate(anyString())).then(new Answer<String>() {    
        @Override
        public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
            String query = (String) invocationOnMock.getArguments[0];
            if (capturedQueries.contains(query)) {
                return null;
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Update string is not as expected: " + query);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: When you put it like this it make sense :) It means that I can't really use multiple 'when' clauses if one of them has any matcher like anyString()...

Comment: @apines: There may be a way of doing it, but I don't know what it is.